# Varying API response from browser and CLI for application deployed through kubernetes Canary

Tags: api, curl, kubernetes, openshift, canary-deployment

I am trying to deploy an application using canary in openshift provider using the steps mentioned in the following website.

https://opensource.com/article/17/5/colorful-deployments

The deployment contains 2 deploymentconfigs, 2 services for both older and the latest versions of the application and a single route to share the traffic between the 2 services.

The older version gives a response as "Hello from Prod" and the latest version gives a response of "Hello from Canary".

And the responses are as expected when checked through CURL commands via CLI.

While checking the same response from browser it is not matching with the responses from CLI.

Let's say the traffic is completely switched to "Prod" service via route, then the response from both CLI and browser are "Hello from Prod".

When the traffic is completely switched to "Canary" service then the response from CLI is "Hello from Canary" but the response from browser is "Hello from Prod".

The issue persists in the browser even after deleting the cookies. Any suggestions here would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like caching. Have you checked the Network tab in the dev tools in the browser to see if it's pulling the response fresh?

Comment: I have checked Network tab and it is pulling the same old response not the fresh one. Deleting the cookies also not helping to pull the fresh response.